# Compatibility of Shorebird In-App Update with Multiple Exported Apps from a Single Project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-update, shorebird

I am currently utilizing Shorebird for implementing an in-app update feature without relying on the respective app stores. My project encompasses the creation of four distinct apps, all derived from a single codebase. These apps differ in various aspects such as app name, bundle identifier, app icon, logo, and server APIs.

The apps are department-specific, and I must maintain separate apps for each department without providing users with the option to select their department within a single app. My concern is regarding the in-app updates – if I release an update for, let's say, department A, will this update also impact departments B, C, and D? Specifically, I want to know if unique identifiers such as app name, bundle identifier, app icon, logo, and server APIs will become uniform across all departments due to the in-app update.

I appreciate any insights or guidance on how to manage updates for multiple apps derived from a single project using Shorebird. Thank you!

I have tried pushing updates for department A, and it is working perfectly, but I still haven't pushed an update on the store (app store & play store) with the shorebird feature on the other department apps (B, C, D).